# Kafka Streaming with apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have setup apache kafka in local machine and working fine, when I post a message into the producer, it is flowing immediately in consumer prompt .

Is it possible to configure continuous file stream from my local folder ? How can I do that ?

can I write a java application to configure my producer ?

Comment: what does "continuous file stream from my local folder" mean ? can you write more detail for it ?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more at low level? I mean "stream from my local folder" is it from IDE? Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

I only know two ways in which it can be done.

1) Write a Kafka Producer and Kafka Consumer. These Producers and Consumer can also be implemented in different languages such as Java, C, and Python.

• The Kafka API for message producers/consumers
• Simple Java-based Kafka producers/Consumers

2) Write a Data Generator Code in Java or any language you prefer and store the data files in your Folder and write a shell script which will contain Kafka In build/API command which will load the data to Kafka Broker and you can consume it when ever you need.

Below is the example of Shell Script.

```
#####################################################################
#############################  COMPLETE SCRIPT  #####################
### HEADER - PROGRAM NAME - <Kafkaload.sh>

bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 4 --topic topicname

for i in $(seq 60)
do
echo $i
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
echo $DATE
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topicname < /home/bhavesh/Fireclickdata$i.txt
done

echo done
```

This Example will load all my files generated by my data generator code to Kafka

**Hope this help!!!...**

Comment: Thanks Bhavesh. Hope it would help.